# Efficient collection for accessing and retrieving sorted items in Java

Tags: java

In my use-case, I have a collection of timepoints which is sorted in ascending order..

```
ArrayList<Double> times=new ArrayList<Double>();
Collections.sort(times);
```

I would like to use an efficient structure, when I give an arbitrary time points (it could be not exist in the list), it should give me the nearest and the largest value in the list with O(1) complexity.

Is there any structure or algorithm which can be used for above?

Comment: I'm not sure if O(1) is possible, a variant of the binary search could give you O(log(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first obvious improvement is to use an `double[]` as this will use a fraction of the memory and have a much better access pattern.  This can be use for `O(log N)` lookup or nearest search which likely to be the best you can achieve.

If you use a hash map you can get O(1) lookup but this won't give you nearest value. If most of your lookup are exact matches, you could use this first and a binary search if you fail to find a match.

You could also consider ordering the values into "buckets" of hours, minute or seconds as appropriate.  This will help reduce the time complexity depending on what assumptions you make.

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) sorts elements according to its natural ordering, so you can get the largest element. Additionally, it defines methods `higher` and `lower`, which retrieve the closer elements.

Having said that, the documentation states that the cost for `contains` operation is O(log N), which I think it's also applicable for `higher` and `lower`, given [it seems to use binary search](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.getHigherEntry%28java.lang.Object%29) to look for the proper entry.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above comments, I am going to use [fastutill collection](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/) such as  LongAVLTreeSet and LongRBTreeSet.

I think these classes give me an optimised performance in terms of both memory consumption and arithmentic calculations.